# Difficulty proving congruence property(Modular Multiplicative Inverse).

Tags: congruences, inverse-function

I watched some posts trying to discover why the modular multiplicative inverse of a given number was unique but i didnt understand why given:

$d_1*e≡ d_2*e ≡ 1 \mod(n)$ we can assume $d_1 ≡ d_1*d_2*e \mod(n)$.

I know it works cause I've tried out some examples like:

$3*5 ≡ 10*5 ≡ 1 \mod(7)$

$3 ≡ 3*10*5 \mod(7)$

$3 ≡ 150 \mod(7)$

$-147 \mod(7) = - 21$

This: $d_1 ≡ d_1*d_2*e \mod(n)$ is the step I'm missing. Can anybody supply me with a proof or the property I'm forgetting?

Comment: In $d_2e \equiv 1 \pmod n$ multiply both sides by $d_1$.

Comment: Use **\mod n** to generate $\mod n$ or for brackets, use **\pmod n** to generate $\pmod n$. It begins with a *p* instead because it stands for *parantheses*. If you want to multiply, use **\cdot** to generate $\cdot$ for things like $a\cdot b$ for example, which is **a\cdot b**. Or, if you want to multiply numbers instead of variables, you can use **\times** to generate $\times$ for things like $3\times 5$ for example, which is **3\times 5**. Remember to always put a dollar sign $\$$ at the start and end of the sentences in bold to generate them, or you could use $\$\$$ instead if you prefer.

Comment: If you want to denote a congruence with the symbol $\equiv$ then this is written as $\to$ $\$$\equiv$\$$ and if you want to write things like $k^2$ or $d_1$ then these are written as $\$$k^2$\$$ and $\$$d_1$\$$. If you want to denote a set $\{x, y, z\}$ for example then this is written as $\to$ $\$$\{x, y, z\}$\$$. This is to help you write posts using LATEX in the future so it is easier for other users like me to understand what your question is. Make sure, in your questions, to always list your skill level and what you attempted yourself in answering the question for errors to be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If $d_2 e \equiv 1$, then $d_1 \equiv d_1 1 \equiv d_1 (d_2 e)$.